# Show that $V=\text{Ker }(P)+{\rm Im}(P)$ and $\text{Ker }(P)\cap {\rm Im}(P)=\{0_v\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $P:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear map such that $P^2=P$, show that show that $V=\text{Ker }(P) + \text{Im }(P)$ and $\text{Ker}(P)\cap \text{Im }(P)=\{0_v\}$.

So I know that $\text{Ker }(P)+\text{Im }(P)\subseteq V$, since each are subspaces of $V$ and their sum is a subspace as well. But I'm having trouble showing the other direction, that $V\subseteq \text{Ker }(P) + \text{Im }(P)$.

Answer (score 4):

For all $x\in V$ we have

$$x=\underbrace{(x-p(x))}_{\in\text{Ker } p}+\underbrace{p(x)}_{\in \text{Im } p}$$

and if $y\in \text{Ker } p\cap \text{Im } p$ then $y=p(x)$ for some $x\in V$ so
$$0=p(y)=p^2(x)=p(x)=y$$
hence

$$\text{Ker } p\cap \text{Im } p=\{0\}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $v \in V$ write
$$v = (v-P(v)) + P(v) \in {\rm Ker} P + {\rm Im} P$$
since $P(v-P(v)) = P(v) - P(P(v)) = P(v) - P(v) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: prove that $\text{ker }(P)\cap \text{im }(P)=\{0_v\}$. Then use the relation:

$$
\text{dim }(A+B) = \text{dim }A + \text{dim }B - \text{dim }A\cap B
$$