# Matrices defining an isomorphism on their image space

Tags: linear-algebra

For a real square matrix $A$ of size $n$ it is true that the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $A$ defines an isomorphism on $Im(A)$
2. $rank(A) = rank(A^2)$
3. $R^n$ is the direct sum of $Im(A)$ and $Ker(A)$

Is there a name for the class of matrices satisfying these conditions?

Comment: This is called [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)). The claim is shown [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995612/show-that-v-kerpimp-and-kerp-cap-imp-0-v).

Comment: In the first condition, it should be homomorphism. right?

Comment: No, I really mean an isomorphism. Any square matrix $A$ defines a linear map on the invariant subspace $Im(A)$ of $R^n$, and I want to know a name for those matrices for which this linear map is an isomorphism. Take for example the matrix with the lines $[1,1,-2]$, $[0,1,-1]$, $[1, -1, 0]$. It has rank 2 and defines an isomorphism of its 2-dimensional image, but it is not a projection.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it has a name. However, What I see is a more general form of projection. So, we have the matrix map $AP$ where $P$ is a projection matrix and $A$ is a matrix of the same or greater rank than $P$ that keeps the input vectors from $P$in the same space. it is not hard to prove that $(AP)^2$ has the same rank as $AP$.

Also, if we have a linear transform (bijective) one space to another, we have the isomorphism property, which should be made by $A$.