# $\text{Ker P $ ,$ Im P}$ and Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

- Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $P:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear map such that $P^2=P$. 
  Show that

$$V=\text{Ker P + Im P}.$$ and $$\text{Ker P}\cap\text{Im P}=\left\{0\right\}.$$

HINT. an element $v\in V$ is $v=v-P(v)+P(v)$.

Proof. Since $P(v-P(v))=P(v)-P^2(v)=0$, we see that $V=\text{Ker P + Im P}.$ **How did we see this, I couldn't understand** As for intersection, note that if $w$ lies in the set  $\text{Ker P}\cap\text{Im P}$, then there exist a vector $v$ such that $P(v)=w$ **I couldn't understand this $P(v)=w$ **, so that $P(v)=P(w)$. But since $P(w)=0$, we conclude that $w=P(v)=0$ **Why?**. Hence

$$V=\text{Ker P + Im P}.$$ and $$\text{Ker P}\cap\text{Im P}=\left\{0\right\}.$$

that is it is direct sum.

**I have a question that I wrote phrases in bold**

Comment: $V \neq kerP + ImP$, are you sure you didn't mean $V = kerP \oplus ImP$ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $V=ker(P)+im(P)$ and $ker(P)\cap im(P)=\{0_v\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995612/show-that-v-kerpimp-and-kerp-cap-imp-0-v)

Comment: @VictoriaM The question is from Lang's Linear Algebra page 71, question 10. And yes, I sure.

Comment: Ah, I just checked the book. The notation $+$ was meant to be $\oplus$. See https://i.imgur.com/Psz82Qy.png

Comment: @VictoriaM Since $\ker P$ and $\operatorname{im}P$ are subspaces of $V$, the two notations are not mutually exclusive, all the more if the condition $\ker P\cap\operatorname{im}P=\{0\}$ holds.

Comment: @VictoriaM The question is essentially to prove $V = \operatorname{Ker} P \oplus \operatorname{Im} P$ in two parts: show $V$ is the sum of these subspaces, then show the sum is direct.

Comment: Edited question, can you see now?

Comment: @VictoriaM Edited question, can you see now?

Comment: @TheoBendit edited question, can you see now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since $P(v−P(v))=P(v)−P^2(v)=0$, we see that $V=\operatorname{Ker} P + \operatorname{Im} P$. **How did we see this, I couldn't understand**

What they're showing here is that $v - P(v) \in \operatorname{Ker} P$. Just consider the definition of $\operatorname{Ker} P$; it's the set of vectors that $P$ sends to $0$. Since they're applying $P$ to $v - P(v)$ and getting $0$, this means $v - P(v) \in \operatorname{Ker} P$.

Couple this with the simple observation that $P(v) \in \operatorname{Im} P$ (it is, after all, the result of applying $P$ to an element of $V$), and this implies that
$$v = \underbrace{P(v)}_{\in \; \operatorname{Im} P} + \underbrace{v - P(v)}_{\in \; \operatorname{Ker} P} \in \operatorname{Im} P + \operatorname{Ker} P.$$

> As for intersection, note that if $w$ lies in the set $\operatorname{Ker} P \cap \operatorname{Im} P$, then there exist a vector $v$ such that $P(v)=w$ **I couldn't understand this**

If $w \in \operatorname{Ker} P \cap \operatorname{Im} P$, then $w \in \operatorname{Im} P$ (it's also true that $w \in \operatorname{Ker} P$, but we don't need this fact just yet). The image of $P$ is the set of all vectors of the form $P(v)$, where $v \in V$. This is literally the definition. To say $w \in \operatorname{Im} P$ is exactly the same thing as saying there is some $v \in V$ such that $w = P(v)$.

> so that $P(v)=P(w)$. But since $P(w)=0$, we conclude that $w=P(v)=0$ **Why?**

We know that $w = P(v)$, by construction of $v$. Applying $P$ to both sides, using the fact that $P^2 = P$, we get
$$P(w) = P^2(v) = P(v).$$
We know that $P(w) = 0$ because $w \in \operatorname{Ker} P$ (remember, $w$ is in both $\operatorname{Ker} P$ and $\operatorname{Im} P$ by assumption!) and the definition of the kernel is the set of vectors that $P$ sends to $0$. So, $P$ sends $w$ to $0$. By the above equality, this means $P(v) = 0$. But, our construction of $v$ was a vector in $V$ such that $w = P(v)$, so joining these equalities up,
$$w = P(v) = 0.$$
That is, the **only** vector in $V$ that lies both in $\operatorname{Ker} P$ and $\operatorname{Im} P$ is the zero vector!

Comment: Than you very much!