# HOw I can start this ?Let M be an R-module and e : M → M a morphism of R-modules such that e 2 = e. Show that M = ker(e) ⊕ Im(e).

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let M be an R-module and e : M → M a morphism of R-modules such
that e
2 = e. Show that M = ker(e) ⊕ Im(e).

Comment: If you don't know how to start, then try to search first, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995612/show-that-v-kerpimp-and-kerp-cap-imp-0-v) for linear maps and vector spaces. Then for modules.

Comment: There has to be a better duplicate somewhere, but at least this is a special case of the linked duplicate where $M=R$, $N=eM$, and $f(m)=e(m)$ and $g$ is $e$ restricted to $eM$. Looking at that post should make it obvious even how to do it from first principles